# PHP is the next key a part of the current?

Tags: php, arrays, iteration

Hey guys I'm trying to see where my pairs of keys stop, I have arrays built like this

**EDIT** People are getting really confused so I'm using a real array instead of an example

```
array (
  'key' => '',
  'po' => '',
  'label' => '',
  'report_key' => '',
  'shipper' => '',
  'status' => '',
  'location' => '',
  'inspector' => '',
  'commodity' => '',
  'brand' => '',
  'case_count' => '',
  'variety' => '',
  'style' => '',
  'grower_lot' => '',
  'pack_date' => '',

  // grouping 4 items
  'berry_size1' => '',
  'berry_size2' => '',
  'berry_size3' => '',
  'berry_size4' => '',

  // grouping 3 items
  'bunch_color1' => '',
  'bunch_color2' => '',
  'bunch_color3' => '',

  // grouping 2 items     
  'color1' => '',
  'color2' => '',


  // grouping 3 items
  'stem1' => '',
  'stem2' => '',
  'stem3' => '',


  // grouping 2 items
  'shatter1' => '',
  'shatter2' => '',


  // grouping 2 items
  'splits1' => '',
  'splits2' => '',


  // grouping 2 items
  'wet_sticky1' => '',
  'wet_sticky2' => '',

  'overall_quality' => '',


  // grouping 2 items
  'sugar_brix1' => '',
  'sugar_brix2' => '',

  'rating' => '',
  'comments' => '',
)
```

I came up with some stupid way that really doesn't work to try and sort things out, its extremely backwards, honestly I'm pretty embarrassed by my attempt.

```
            foreach($obj as $key=>$val) {

            if(strpos(  preg_replace('/[^a-z]/i', '', $key), 
                        preg_replace('/[^a-z]/i', '', $all_keys[$key+$b+1])
                        ) !== false) { echo "<p>$key</p>"; // items 1-3 will show
            } elseif(strpos(preg_replace('/[^a-z]/i', '', $key), 
                            preg_replace('/[^a-z]/i', '', $all_keys[$key+$b-1])
                            ) !== false) { echo "<p>$key</p>"; // show last item
            } else {

                  $in.='<aside class="left">';
                    $in .= "<label for='$key'>". ucwords(strtolower(str_replace('_',' ',$key))) ."</label><br/>";
                    $in .= ($key=='key') ? "<input type='text' value='". $objLastId ."' id='$key' class='disabled' disabled='disabled'>" : "<input type='text' value='' name='$key' id='$key'>";
                  $in.='</aside>';

              $b++;
              }
            }
```

Anyway what I'm really trying to achieve is something like this, could someone steer me in the right direction please?

```
<style>
 .row2 input {width: 50px !important;}
 .row3 input {width: 27px !important;}
 .row4 input {width: 15px !important;}
</style>

// stem was a 2 item group, so should have the row4 class
// and should have the second item appended by a &nbsp; 
// all be inside the same grouping, like below ...
<aside class="left row2">
<label for="color1">Color</label>
<br/><input type="text" value="" name="color1" id="color1">
&nbsp;<input type="text" value="" name="color2" id="color2">
</aside>


// stem was a 3 item group, so should have the row4 class
// and should have items 2-3 appended by a &nbsp; all be inside 
// the same grouping, like below ...
<aside class="left row3">
<label for="stem1">Stem</label>
<br><input type="text" id="stem1" name="stem1" value="">
&nbsp;<input type="text" id="stem2" name="stem2" value="">
&nbsp;<input type="text" id="stem3" name="stem3" value="">
</aside>


// berry_size was a 4 item group, so should have the row4 class
// and should have items 2-4 appended by a &nbsp; all be inside 
// the same grouping, like below ...
<aside class="left row4">
<label for="berry_size1">Berry Size</label>
<br/><input type="text" id="berry_size1" name="berry_size1" value="">
&nbsp;<input type="text" id="berry_size2" name="berry_size2" value="">
&nbsp;<input type="text" id="berry_size3" name="berry_size3" value="">
&nbsp;<input type="text" id="berry_size4" name="berry_size4" value="">
</aside>

... or ...

// this is a single, so no extra class and ....
<aside class="left">
<label for="other_item">Other Item</label>
<br/><input type="text" id="other_item" name="other_item" value="">
</aside>
```

What I see this really boiling down to is reading the next array keys name (I stripped the name and used the integer in my version), atleast I think that's the right way to do it?

Comment: It is easier, probably, to change the format of the array

Comment: You can't have three times the same key in your array, namely `other_item`. Please elaborate, otherwise your problem is not really clear (strictly spoken).

Comment: I agree with Cheery on this one. Try going for an array of arrays.

Comment: Do you really need markup (`<aside>`) or is it just a visual problem you could solve with CSS?

Comment: THis comes straight from a DB, I'm not going to be able to alter it unless I A). restructure the db B). create a multidimensional array out of this (which would probably end up working the same as pure output) =(

Comment: @hakre it doesn't matter what it is, I just chose aside, the 'other_stuff' is just other example items, I just threw them in so people knew that there was other stuff in the array besides stuff ending with a integer

Comment: @hakre here's a real array http://pastiebin.com/?page=p&id=4f443e66e1592

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  $arr = array(
    'other_item' => 'value',

    // this one ranges 1-3
    'first_name1' => 'value',
    'first_name2' => 'value',
    'first_name3' => 'value',

    // this one ranges 1-4
    'next_name1' => 'value',
    'next_name2' => 'value',
    'next_name3' => 'value',
    'next_name4' => 'value',

    'other_item' => 'value',

    // this one ranges 1-4
    'last_name1' => 'value',
    'last_name2' => 'value',
    'last_name3' => 'value',
    'last_name4' => 'value',

    'other_item' => 'value'
);

$newarr = array();
foreach($arr as $key=>$value)
{
    if (preg_match('#^([^\d]+)#', $key, $matches)===1)
     $newarr[$matches[1]][] = $value;  
}
print_r($newarr);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [other_item] => Array
        (
            [0] => value
        )

    [first_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => value
            [1] => value
            [2] => value
        )

    [next_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => value
            [1] => value
            [2] => value
            [3] => value
        )

    [last_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => value
            [1] => value
            [2] => value
            [3] => value
        )

)
```

And do whatever you want to do with it. Like that code (just an example, not a very nice one)

```
foreach($newarr as $name => $block)
{
  $cnt = count($block);
  echo '<aside class="left'.($cnt>1?' row' . $cnt:'').'">
        <label for="' . $name . ($cnt>1?'1':''). '">' . 
               ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', $name)) . '</label>
        <br/>';
  foreach($block as $key=>$element)
  {
   echo ($key>0?'&nbsp;':'') . '<input type="text" value="" name="' . $name . 
        ($cnt>1?($key+1):'') . '" id="' . $name . 
        ($cnt>1?($key+1):'') . '">' . "\n";
  }
  echo '</aside>' . "\n";
}
```

It gives:

```
<aside class="left">
<label for="other_item">Other Item</label>
<br/><input type="text" value="" name="other_item" id="other_item">
</aside>
<aside class="left row3">
<label for="first_name1">First Name</label>
<br/><input type="text" value="" name="first_name1" id="first_name1">
&nbsp;<input type="text" value="" name="first_name2" id="first_name2">
&nbsp;<input type="text" value="" name="first_name3" id="first_name3">
</aside>
<aside class="left row4">
<label for="next_name1">Next Name</label>
<br/><input type="text" value="" name="next_name1" id="next_name1">
&nbsp;<input type="text" value="" name="next_name2" id="next_name2">
&nbsp;<input type="text" value="" name="next_name3" id="next_name3">
&nbsp;<input type="text" value="" name="next_name4" id="next_name4">
</aside>
<aside class="left row4">
<label for="last_name1">Last Name</label>
<br/><input type="text" value="" name="last_name1" id="last_name1">
&nbsp;<input type="text" value="" name="last_name2" id="last_name2">
&nbsp;<input type="text" value="" name="last_name3" id="last_name3">
&nbsp;<input type="text" value="" name="last_name4" id="last_name4">
</aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell you just want to modify your output based on your 'key type'. I am thinking something like this:

```
foreach($obj as $key => $val)
{
    $parts = explode('_', $key);
    switch($parts[0])
    {
        case 'first':
            // Do something here
            break;
        case 'other':
            // Do something here
            break;
        case 'next':
            // Do something here
            break;
        case 'last':
            // Do something here
            break;
    }
}
```

I think I might be missing something however, as you appear to be checking 'next' elements...

Comment: No I'm trying to edit it based on the integer at the back of the key

Comment: Hmm, if you need to count the number of each type, then @Cheery has got the right idea, I think :)